# Find the limit: $\lim_{x\to -1}\frac{1+x^{\frac{1}{5}}}{1+x^{\frac{1}{3}}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Find the limit:

$$\lim_{x\to -1}\frac{1+x^{\frac{1}{5}}}{1+x^{\frac{1}{3}}}$$

I tried using the formula for the sum of the cubes in the denominator but then I don't know what to do with the numerator. Hints?

Comment: Is l'Hospital's rule allowed?

Comment: @user296113 No.

Comment: Q. : "Is l'Hospital's rule allowed?" A.: "No". Post: "By Lopital..." Decision: Accept! After 12 minutes. Sorry but **what is going on here?**

Comment: @Did I accepted Michael Rozenberg's answer because I found the formula for $a^5+b^5$ useful, not because of L'Hopital's rule.

Comment: How did you use this hint, already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Lopital 
$$\lim\limits_{x\to -1}\frac{1+x^{\frac{1}{5}}}{1+x^{\frac{1}{3}}}=\lim\limits_{x\to -1}\frac{\frac{1}{5}x^{-\frac{4}{5}}}{\frac{1}{3}x^{-\frac{2}{3}}}=\frac{3}{5}$$
Also you can use $a^5+b^5=(a+b)(a^4-a^3b+a^2b^2-ab^3+b^4)$

and $a^3+b^3=(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)$

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=u^{15}$ and then 
$$\lim_{u\to-1}\frac{1+u^3}{1+u^5}$$
Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x) = x^{1/5}, g(x)= x^{1/3}.$ The expression equals

$$\tag 1 \frac{f(x)-f(-1)}{g(x)-g(-1)}= \frac{(f(x)-f(-1))/(x-(-1))}{(g(x)-g(-1))/(x-(-1))}.$$

By definition of the derivative, $(1)\to f'(-1)/g'(-1)$ as $x\to -1.$ This an easy computation, and no L'Hopital was used.